# Receive all message queued in durable topic subscriber in between mule flow

Tags: mule, activemq-classic, mule-component, jms-topic

I wanted to retrieve all message queued in durable topic subscriber in between mule flow. I have tried to use Mule requester but for JMS inbount durable topic subscriber we have to prove "durableName" attribute. Its working fine with inbound endpoint but unable to figure out how to call it in between the flow execution.
 Please find the code below

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" clientId="xyz-001" password="admin" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" persistentDelivery="true"/>
<mulerequester:config name="Mule_Requester" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="activemqtestFlow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/getTopicMessages" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="jms://testTopic?connector=Active_MQ" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="subscriber two pay load" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

Following flow works fine, but I want to achieve in between mule flow call for JMS topic,

```
<flow name="activemqtestFlow1">
   <jms:inbound-endpoint  connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"  topic="testTopic" durableName="xyz-001">
          <jms:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Please suggest the workaround for this.

Comment: You can use a java component and dispatch all messages from queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durable topic subscriber for mule requester can be achieved by creating a generic endpoint and by passing topic, durable , durableName properties to it.

Only issue with this approach is , studio will show validation errors while using properties element which we need to ignore and deploy the application.

Endpoint will be like

```
<endpoint name="durablesubscriberEndpoint" connector-ref="Active_MQ" address="jms://testTopic" doc:name="Generic">
    <property value="true" key="durable"/>
    <property value="subscriber-name" key="durableName"/>
    <property value="true" key="topic"/>
</endpoint>
```

And mule requester can be called as

```
<mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester"  resource="durablesubscriberEndpoint" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
```

It works like charm...!!

Another way to make it more generic and dynamic one can use following

```
<set-variable variableName="resource" value="jms://#[message.inboundProperties.activeMQTopic]?connector=Active_MQ&amp;durable=true&amp;durableName=#[message.inboundProperties.'subscriber-name']&amp;topic=true" doc:name="Variable"/>
<mulerequester:request-collection doc:name="Mule Requester" config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="#[flowVars.resource]"/>
```